# How to get response for login api to perform login using volley for this json data with Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: android, json, authentication, android-volley

```
{  
   "status":"success",
   "contents":[  
      {  
         "id":"100",
         "event":"",
         "name":"ww",
         "email":"abc@gmail.com",
         "phone":"",
         "zip_code":"",
         "state":"",
         "password":"@ww",
         "sports_id":"3",
         "sports_name":"BASEBALL",
         "mascoat_name":"ww",
         "logo":"https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg",
         "logo1":"https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg",
         "file":"http:\/\/something.com\/assets_admin\/uploads\/file\/",
         "status":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

For this Json Data, I have params, Content-type, and URL. How to perform login using volley for this Json Response.

Answer (score 1):

### try this...

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

 String status= json.getString("status");
 JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("contents");

 JSONObject c = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
 String emil= c.getString("email");
 //remaining data you will
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this project will help you link: https://github.com/probelalkhan/android-login-example-using-volley

Comment: I am unable to get a response. Should I use StringRequest for my Json Response?StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivityclass);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }